# 2010 to 2013 migration - Can't get rid of MissingFeature warnings

Tags: 2013, 2010, migration, feature, upgrade

I am in the process of migrating SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013.

I already solved a huge amount of problems with "MissingFeature", "MissingWebPart",  "MissingSetupFile", "MissingAssembly" and so on.

I am down to 6 "MissingFeature" when I run a test on the database. My problem is that I can't get rid of those warnings. When I query the Features table for the ID I can't find it.

Unfortunately it is not an option to remove those features in the production system so I have to restore the content database in my test system and solve problems there.

I also tried Feature Admin 3 but the missing features aren't showing up there either.

Is there any other way to get rid of those errors?

Comment: to my experience it seems to be hard and dangerous as well. I tried it concerning MissingWebPart notifications. After having deleted several id references in database tables of a test migration site I deleted the references in 15-Hive and webconfig on the SP-Server as well. It ended up with a 500 internal error on any url of the site.

Comment: Can you edit your original post with the GUIDs of the features? You can also use FeatureAdmin (https://www.featureadmin.com/) to prune orphaned features.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, even though we get warning during the migration due to the missing features, it won't break the functionality, we can see there are many missing higher versions of SharePoint while we do the migration of previous versions content db migration, even though those features don't exists in the source system as well,but still we get those warning, we have to live with that.

Refer to the below article for cleaning up and some tricks about the migration:

[SharePoint Migration: Basic tips and tricks in migration project](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-2/basic-tips-and-tricks-in-sharepoint-migration-project/)